# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException Not working

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to get an unhandled exception handler to work but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I have to following in the constructor:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
```

And this furthur down

```
static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
        if (log != null)
        {
            if (args.IsTerminating)
                log.LogError(e.Message, e.Source, e.InnerException.Message);
            else
                log.LogWarning(e.Message, e.Source, e.InnerException.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly exe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            string exeDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exe.Location);
            File.WriteAllText(DocuPath.Join(exeDir, "Emergency.log"), e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

log is a static object which handles logging to a file. Why don't I get a message in either the log file written to by the object or Emergency.log?

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see if it's getting hit.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is throwing the exception that you're expecting to get handled here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `e.InnerException` is null you get an exception inside this method.
I don't think it is a good idea to have this problem here.

Try with this.

```
 string innerMessage = e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : string.Empty;
 if (args.IsTerminating)
     log.LogError(e.Message, e.Source, innerMessage);
 else
     log.LogWarning(e.Message, e.Source, innerMessage);
```